# Increment X Mod N in One Line

Tags: java, c

I have several small programs that require infinitely looping over the integer set **Z** sub n. I often write the code in this manor:

```
int x = 0;
int n = 13; //or some other prime
while(1) {
  //do stuff dependent on x
  ++x;
  x %= n;
}
```

I write code mostly in C/C++ & Java so I was wondering:

Is there a way to increment x mod n in one line rather then two in either language?

Comment: Failing all else, there's always `x = (x+1)%n`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you considered:

```
x = (x + 1 == n ? 0: x + 1);
```

The chances are the `x + 1` will optimise to one instruction and at least you are guaranteed to never use division (which a bad optimiser might use when `%` is involved).

Comment: My first response was "Huh???"  It took me a few moments before I said "Ah!".  Very, very good suggestion!  For precisely the reasons you cited (it's not just "clever" - it's genuinely optimal!)

Comment: While `x=(x+1)%n` is most simple to read, `x=(x+1==n) ? 0 : x+1;` is definitely optimal by avoiding `%` the modulo operator. Nice Answer!

Comment: `x = (++x >= n? 0 : x);`` gurantuees one less addition. And the ``>=`` takes care of cases where the variable might be modified elsewhere without being slower in execution time. Super nitpicky, but doesn't hurt doing things right.

Answer (score 7):

```
x = (x + 1) % n;
```

Not terribly surprising.

Comment: This is messier than the other answers, and yet the most understandable IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

`if (++x == n) x = 0;`

Using `x = (x + 1 == n ? 0 : x + 1);` requires two additions: one for the comparison and another when the value of `x` is set to `x + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is this

```
x = ++x % n;  // Java
```

Comment: No!  `x = (++x) % n`: Yes.  `x = ++x % n`: undefined behavior - Bad!

Comment: @paulsm4 It is not undefined behaviour. C operator precedence is here: http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

Comment: @xagyg From C, probably. It's UB's poster child there.

Comment: @xagyg Operator precedence is irrelevant. `x = ++x % n;` modifies `x` twice without intervening sequence point.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you point me to somewhere that explains this. I would have thought ++x would evaluate (because ++ always does its thing first), then modulo, then assignment. What is undefined about it? Happy to learn. I remember 15 years ago a weird C compiler treated x = -1 the same a x -= 1 so I had to do x = (-1) to assign a negative number. That was an oddity, but curious to find out what you mean.

Comment: Section 6.5 (2) in C2011 (n1570 draft): "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
effect occurs in any of the orderings." with accompanying footnote "This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as `i = ++i + 1;` ...". Same thing, different verbiage in C99.

Comment: Wow, a compiler that had `=op` instead of `op=` 15 years ago? That's impressive, the old `=op` syntax was abolished long before K&R came out. Accepting that was a no-no already 30 years ago.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the explanation and reference. Answer updated.

Comment: @xagyg It's still UB in C (it's correct in Java, since that prescribes evaluation order). The parentheses do nothing. You modify `x` twice, once with the `++` and once with the `=`. The storing of the incremented value in `x` due to the `++` and the storing of `(x+1)%n` in `x` are unsequenced relative to each other. Both writes must have occurred when the `;` is reached(¹), but which occurs first isn't prescribed. (¹)Well, except it's explicitly undefined behaviour, so the standard doesn't forbid eliminating the entire expression or any parts of it.